# No "Asynchronous Sending" Option in my Magento 2 Admin panel

Tags: magento2

I am facing an issue with order confirmation emails from being sent and I suspect that it has happened due to the failure of Cron jobs, somehow it got messed up, however we think it will take time to fix, however order confirmation emails are not being sent because cron jobs are needed for that.

However, I found out that **Asynchronous Sending** when disabled the emails will be sent without the help of any Cron job:

https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/email-communications.html

As shown in the official docs, I went to the exact place **Stores > Configuration > Sales > Sales Email**

But it isn't there.

Any idea what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

1. On the Admin sidebar, tap **Stores**. > **Settings** > **Configuration**.
2. In the panel on the left under **Sales** > **Sales Emails** > **General 
   Settings** section.
3. Set **Asynchronous** sending to “**Enable**”.
4. When complete, tap **Save Config**.

   https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/email-communications.html